# Need System Settings Icon back on Launcher

Tags: 14.04, launcher, icons, system, settings

So plain and simple. I've never uses Ubuntu in my life. I was playing around with the launcher shortcuts on the left side of my window, and I decided to "unlock system settings" from the launcher. How do I get it back since clearly system settings is something I would like to use. The icon for system settings is the Grey cog wheel looking thing. I looked around in some files but can't seem to find it anywhere. If anyone knows how I can get this back, please let me know right away and I will be sure to be more careful next time. Also to reiterate: The icon was removed by me, this has nothing to do with any update issues or corrupted icons disappearing after updates. This was entirely my fault.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can lock any app to Launcher by dragging its icon from Dash and releasing it somewhere on Launcher, or by opening it from Dash, right clicking on its Launcher icon and selecting **Lock to Launcher**.

[image: Lock to Launcher]